# Why are all my pages returning 404 headers despite working fine?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, http-headers, front-controller

All the pages on my site work fine. But they're being sent with a `404` header.

I've got a PHP website using the front controller pattern. `.htaccess` has the standard code to deliver page name requests as URL params:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?filename=$1
```

In `index.php` I grab that URL parameter and use it this way:

```
$_pagename = $_GET['filename'];
$content = "pages/" . $_pagename . ".php";
if (!file_exists($content)) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    $content = "pages/404.php";
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 202 Accepted');
}
```

See, I've even manually given it a `202` header. (Which should not be necessary!)

Everything seems to be working properly. `$content` is loaded correctly, nonexistent pages are delivered the `404` correctly. The only weird thing is that all pages have the `404` header! What could be causing this?

Comment: Well, given the code, the only way that could happen is if `file_exists` is returning false every time. So either that's the case, or something else is happening later in the code that you haven't provided.

Comment: Just one more note, you should run that `$_pagename` against a whitelist, to prevent yourself from [LFI (Local File Inclusion)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Local_File_Inclusion).

Comment: Your condition should be ok because your pages works ok otherwise you should see only 404 page. Maybe the 200 header is not working? Try [http_response_code()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Comment: @JonStirling was correct, later in the code I accidentally set the header again.

Comment: @Darren, thanks for pointing that out. Instead of checking if the file exists, I should check that it's one of the files in my `pages` directory. Thanks.

Comment: @brentonstrine exactly right! It's always better to have a set list (array) of files you will only allow users to access.